# Float number suffix when saving $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] as cookie

Tags: php, apache, cookies, uri, setcookie

I'm trying to do a simple thing in PHP and saving the currently visited page to a cookie by saving the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

However, the cookie value always include a float number such as `path/to/file.php?0.449978803506048`. If the URI includes parameters these are stripped and replaced by the float number.

Visiting the page `path/to/file.php?param=value`:

```
<?php
    $this_page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
    echo $this_page; // returns: path/to/file.php?param=value

    setcookie("last_page", $this_page, time()+3600);

    echo $_COOKIE['last_page']; // returns: path/to/file.php?0.449978803506048
?>
```

The number changes for each page reload which leads me to belive it has something to do with a timestamp. Is there a PHP setting or something that I need to be aware of? The result is the same in different browsers and I've also tried to encode the value in base 64 before saving the cookie but the result is still the same.

I'm usually not programming much PHP so it might be a very simple solution to this, but I cannot find it!

Running on a Apache 2.2.20 with PHP Version 5.3.6 on Ubuntu Server 11.10 (GNU/Linux 3.0.0-16-server x86_64).

Comment: This looks like a JQuery Ajax call (it adds a random number when you do a call with caching disabled). Do you have Ajax calls in your client-side code?

Comment: Try to delete all cookies in your browser and reload your page.

Comment: Also, note that setcookie() will NOT change the values of the $_COOKIE array in the current page. You will see the changes on the next page load.

Comment: @EmilVikström: You're correct, I'm doing an ajax call which causes this! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, 
I think you misunderstand the setcookie effect, infact it don't change the **current** value of $_COOKIE variable, so a correct version of your code can be this following:

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['last_page'] )){
        echo  "cookie: ". $_COOKIE['last_page'] .'</br>';   // echo the current val of cookie 
}

$this_page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo "this val". $this_page ."</br>"; // returns: path/to/file.php?param=value

//setcookie("last_page", $this_page, time()+3600,'/');
setcookie("last_page", $this_page, time()+3600);

?>
```

The fractional number come from ajax/javascript call (I'm sure at 99.99%), you can see it in access_log, if you see **always** the fractional value, you will found a set of couples in the log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2012:11:06:04 +0200]  "GET /index.php?0.1234567784534 HTTP/1.1" "-" 
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2012:11:06:04 +0200]  "GET /index.php?param=val HTTP/1.1" "-"
```

EDIT

Best solution(?) to detect if a request is ajax or not:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']==='XMLHttpRequest';){
     // this is an ajax request
} else {
    // set cookie
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know my example wasn't entirely correct, sorry about that and thanks for the improved example code! As both you and Emil Vikström pointed out, I'm doing an ajax request to the same page which causes my problem. I solved it by making sure the ajax call doesn't set the cookie by using a URL param. Works, but is it the best solution?

Comment: See the EDIT in the tail of my post. May be it's not the best solution, but it's a good solution, instead of add a parameter to the request.